# Strange URL returned when GeoServer WMS layer added to OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers-2

I want to add a WMS layer from GeoServer to an OpenLayers website. However, when I try to load it into the website, I get following error in the console:

```
GET localhost:8080/geoserver/test/wms?%20LAYERS=test.put_25_vlak_1_vulling&SERV…=
&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-90,0,0,90&WIDTH=256
&HEIGHT=256 net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

I have tried to follow [this](http://this) link, but I suspect that I have made a syntax error somewhere.

Details are as follows:

workspace name: test
layer name:put_25_vlak_1_vulling

```
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "World Map", "localhost:8080/geoserver/test/wms", 
    { layers:'test.put_25_vlak_1_vulling'
    } ); 
    map.addLayer(wms);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: Try with `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/test/wms`

Comment: ah yes! that worked, the error is gone. Still dont see anything but the error is at least gone. Now i only see pink rectangles